# How to get ebay item id from full ebay item url?

Tags: php, url-parsing

I'm studing about ebay api's on these days but stil i cant figure out how to get ebay item id using full item url`(http://www.ebay.com/ctg/TomTom-XXL-550M-US-including-Puerto-Rico-Canada-Mexico-Automotive-GPS-Receiver-/86127922?)`?

i tried in many ways but negetive pls help me!is there any using apis? or any other way i just need the ebay item number..

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get ebay item details from item id via php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404364/how-to-get-ebay-item-details-from-item-id-via-php)

Comment: no this is totally different from that.i need the item id here to find da details f that item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't tested, just wrote it out real quick. It should at the very least give you the general idea. It assumes that the id will always be the segment of the url after the last `/`. If thats not the case, this answer will be pretty useless.

```
$ebayUrl = "http://www.ebay.com/ctg/TomTom-XXL-550M-US-including-Puerto-Rico-Canada-Mexico-Automotive-GPS-Receiver-/86127922?";
$pos     = strrpos($ebayUrl, '/') + 1;
$id      = substr($ebayUrl, $pos);

//if you want to remove the question mark left at the end
$id      = str_replace("?", "", $id);

echo $id;
```

Comment: this returns the id but i cnt use it for my ebay api functions , they says invalid item number! http://open.api.sandbox.ebay.com/shopping?callname=GetSingleItem&responseencoding=XML&appid=paymelk0a-4057-4382-a2b3-5883c34aec9&siteid=0&ItemID=86127922&version=765

Comment: yea, there's a bug. one second.

Comment: okay, i added a tested version. I was off by one character on the last one. We needed to add one to not include the final `/`

Comment: they say here people can search by item number in normal site search but when searching it says no results found http://pages.ebay.ca/help/search/questions/search-item-number.html

Comment: $id1 = str_replace("?", "", $id);
$id2 = str_replace("/", "", $id1);

Comment: im done with da stripping the item id from url but that id z nt working with ebay api..

Comment: yea, I just assumed that number in the url was the item id. If that isn't the case, you'll need to find out what an item Id is, if you can determine it from the id in the url, and if it is not determinable from the contents of the url, you'll have to use the API to get it somehow. I've never used their API. Good luck.

Comment: yeah i'll follow that & thank you for helping me! allthebest.

Comment: @AndyGroff Please check out a very similar [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12641260/ebay-api-get-single-item-by-id) I just posted.

Comment: is it possible to get category id of the product if i have the url of the product?

Answer (score 1):

Other alternative could be:

```
$parts = explode('/', 'http://www.ebay.com/ctg/TomTom-XXL-550M-US-including-Puerto-Rico-Canada-Mexico-Automotive-GPS-Receiver-/86127922?');
$id = trim(end($parts), '?');
echo $id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on where you need to do this, you may be able to use `ebayItemID`

e.g. (javascript) `var itemid = ebayItemID;`

I've used this method to add a 'buy now' button to product descriptions.